# Ajax load php file auto and let user scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am doing a chat room. I successfully load a php file with chat messages. and with auto scroll down to the bottom function, looks good.

the problems is:

when user try to scroll it up. they will have problem to see top messages because the auto scroll down to the bottom function.

I need to solve this problem then user can see top messages and the div still auto load the latest messages so they can still scroll down to see latest messages.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="chat" class="chat"></div>

function chat_update(url,tag){
        var callAjax = function(){
            $.ajax({
                method:'get',
                url:url+'.php',
                success:function(data){
                    $("#"+tag).html(data);
                    $('#chat').scrollTop($('#chat')[0].scrollHeight - $('#chat')[0].clientHeight);
                }
            });
        }
        setInterval(callAjax,1000);
}

$(function() {
    chat_update('chat','chat');
});
```

please help, thanks.

Comment: is it possible to and a checkbox like "autoscroll" and only if its set, the ajax call ill scroll down? What should happen if the user scrolled to the top and a new message is comming in?

Comment: I need this effect: http://jsfiddle.net/dotnetCarpenter/KpM5j/

Comment: I just find the way out. no need extra code. just load the page first, and scroll it down, then update it without the chat line.